# Get the redirected URL of an Ajax call / Open an hidden InAppBrowser Sencha 2.2.1

Tags: ajax, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, inappbrowser

I am working with a Sencha Touch 2.2.1 application. In my application, I am using Ajax call to perform an activity. The URL I specified in Ajax request will redirect to some other URL after execution. To complete my process I need to get that URL. I went through almost all questions regarding the topic in `stackoverflow`. Unfortunately nothing works. I tried `getAllResponseHeaders()` and some other answers I found in `stackoverflow`.

I tried to open that Ajax `url:` value in `window.open()` function in *InAppBrowser*. But It Opens a new window. I don't need it. So to solve this problem, that is to get the new URL, I think there are 2 ways.

1. Any mechanism to return(get) the redirected URL to the Ajax call
2. Any way to open a hidden **InAppBrowser** and execute the URL & get the result.

Second way is the best I think, But any helps regarding the topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG !!

Finally I found out it.

To get the *Redirected URL* I give the URL to an InAppBrowser. My problem was how to open the browser window in hidden mode..!!  The latest Cordova docs explains about it. I was referring the old docs. That's why I didn't get the answer. The Solution I found out is this: when open *InAppBrowser* open it in hidden mode..! That's all..!!

```
var ref = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes');
```

This `hidden=yes` solved my problem.

Comment: lived the same experience. That hidden option need to be more visible in docs.